# Inserting a name with ' in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

First time with this trouble when dealing with a MySQL table.

I'm inserting bar names in a table. If the bar is called "Tim's Bar" and I insert it straight away I get an error and the data is not inserted.

How do you instert properly the ' in the table?

Comment: @user712027, it sounds like you have a SQL-injection problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use mysql_real_escape_string():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: This is the correct solution. This automates what the other answers do.

Answer (score 5):

Use [PDO](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with prepared statements.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO bars (name) VALUES (?)');
$query->execute("Tim's Bar");
```

It's superior (and safer) than using the mysql(i)_* family of functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO your_table SET person_name = 'Tim\'s Bar';
```

Note the \'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should insert it as `'Tim\'s Bar'`.

Regards

Comment: This is overkill, `"Tim's Bar"` or `'Tim\'s Bar'` will suffice

Answer (score 0):

addslashes() by the insert, and stripslashes() by the output would also work

Comment: This is outright incorrect, on both counts. First, `addslashes` is *not* the way to escape data before inserting it into the database. Second, calling `stripslashes` on data going from the database to the screen is not only unnecessary, doing so will corrupt your data.